# Windows Connect to Mapped Network Drive Letter without File explorer

Tags: windows, network-drive

How can I connect to an already mapped network drive on the command line (i.e. without using File Explorer)?

I'd like to be able to run something like

```
C:\Users\ZaneDufour> some_command "D"
C:\Users\ZaneDufour> D:
D:\>
```

Whereas, at the moment, I have to open up File explorer and type `S:\` into the command line.

(The idea with this is that I would like to be able to create a script that runs on startup to ping my network drive, so that I can use my text editor to open up files on the network drive without having to open file explorer first.)

Thanks a ton, and sorry if I missed a similar question that was already answered. It's hard to search through all of the questions about more common network drive issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's the net use command. Here's the syntax:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Adding an example, as suggested:

Assuming that you want to map a drive on a computer named "SERVER01" that shares it's C: drive as "DRIVEC" and you want to access it as drive F:

`net use F: \\SERVER01\DRIVEC`

Comment: @LPChip thanks, I should have remembered to have done that.

Comment: Voted up. :) good answer.